# Collection of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that each subcollection of $n$ distinct vectors is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Question:** Is is possible to find uncountable collection $\mathcal{C}$ of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that every subset $A\subseteq \mathcal{C}$ such that $|A|=n$ is linearly independent?

**Attempt:** When $n=2$, I found that the "open quadrant of a circle" works. More precisely, $\mathcal{C}:=\{(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)|\theta \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})\}$ satisfies the required properties. I tried to inductively make it work for $n\geq 3$. However, I find it hard to prove independence. For instance, I tried to lift the quadrant of a circle continuously over the surface of the quadrant of a hemisphere and considering the vectors corresponding to the lifted set of points.

**Context:** I was reading Rotman's text on Algebraic Topology. I quote the following result from the chapter on simplexes:

> For every $k\geq 0$, euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains $k$ points in general position.

A set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be in general position if every $n+1$ of its points forms an affine independent set. I was wondering if a similar statement holds true for linear independence. Any hints or ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you want to find a subset in a matrix, readings about "spark of a matrix", or the literature in sparse signal recovery might be of help. I am not sure if it could be also for your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The following set is an example of such a set:
$$\{(1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{n-1}) \in \Bbb{R}^n : x \in \Bbb{R}\}.$$
If you take any $n$ vectors from this set and put them as rows into a matrix, you obtain a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Such matrices are known, from the computation of their determinant, to be invertible when their rows are distinct. So, choosing any distinct $n$ vectors from this set will produce a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$, as required.

Comment: +1 Very cute. ${}{}$